# Customize the digital clock

Tags: android, clock

I am using the digital clock but i need a simple customisation to it. My code is like this.

```
 DigitalClock digitalClock=new DigitalClock(this);  
 //Set of attributes  
 digitalClock.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
 setContentView(digitalClock);
```

It displays the time in hr:min:sec format. I want it to look like hr:min format and also I want it in 24hour format. 
I am suspecting that I should use the calendar apis and use string format api. But I am not sure with the best approach.
Any suggestion is precious.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time format is hard-coded, so you can't change it. The only way to change it is to re-implement `DigitalClock` widget. Yo can get source code from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/DigitalClock.java).

Comment: when u say re-implement digital clock do u mean overriding some APIs of digital clock?

Comment: No, this class is not designed for subclassing and overriding methods. You can make your class with similar functionality based on `DigitalClock`'s source code.

Comment: yes I just did it works great thank you. Now I am working to remove the second part. thanks

Comment: I want to display the current time in military format + 1 hour and current time in military format - 1 hour what do u suggest?

Comment: got it. it works with mCalendar.add(mCalendar.HOUR, 1); and mCalendar.add(mCalendar.HOUR, -1);